# What should we call a table that stores changes to another table?

Tags: database-design

At the moment, we have a `Persons` Table. But we also need another table to store changes made to that `Persons` Table. But, my question is, what naming convention is used for tables that store changes made to other database tables.

Comment: Auditing or Tracking.

Answer (score 1):

In our company, we use to suffix the table name with `_history`. So, for the `persons` table you might have a table named `persons_history`.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally dependent on opinions. There is no right or wrong answer to this question.

if you are using SQL Server, then the naming convention that I would follow is

databasename.schema_nmae.tableName.

So for storing changes made to `Persons` table, it will be `schema_name.AUDIT_PERSONS`. Make sure you are in the right database when you create the table. For sql server 2005 and up, dbo is the default schema.